# Verify proof about limit comparison test for series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I have to proof that if $\sum x_{n}$ and $\sum y_{n}$ where $x_{n}$ and $y_{n}$ are positive and if:
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_{n}}{y_{n}}= +\infty
\end{eqnarray}
If $\sum y_{n}$ diverges then $\sum x_{n}$ diverges.

---

Proof:

---

By hypotesis, for all $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, there existe $N_{\beta}\in \mathbb{N}$ sucht that if $n\geq N_{\beta}$ then
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{x_{n}}{y_{n}}> \beta
\end{eqnarray}
So, $y_{n}>0$ we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\beta y_{n}<x_{n}
\end{eqnarray}
Then by comparison test, if $\sum y_{n}$ diverges then $\sum x_{n}$ diverges. Am I right? I'm appretiate your observation if you have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your $\beta$ to be a specific positive number such as $\beta =1$ to make your proof more elegant.

Comment: Thank you, I will apply your suggest

Comment: Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems not complete with all the necessary details and somewhat circular since you are invoking the comparison test you are proving.

We can proceed as follows

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_{n}}{y_{n}}= \infty \implies  \exists n_0 \quad \forall n\ge n_0 \quad x_{n}\ge y_{n}$$

and

$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=n_0}^N y_{n} = \infty \iff \forall M\quad \exists N_0 \quad \forall N\ge N_0 \quad \sum_{n=n_0}^{N} y_{n}\ge M$$

and therefore

$$\forall M\quad \exists N_0 \quad \forall N\ge N_0 \quad \sum_{n=n_0}^{N} x_{n}\ge\sum_{n=n_0}^{N} y_{n}\ge  M \iff \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=n_0}^N x_{n}= \infty$$